# Kubernetes cluster wont auto-scale down to default node counts as it scales up

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I have a three-node cluster, called node A, B, C, and it scales up because I have a deployment with HPA.
When HPA scales up, the cluster nodes scales up too. But when HPA scales down to 1 pod(default), the cluster nodes will sometimes remain at 4 nodes.

I think the reason is that:
When HPA scales down, it terminates pods until reach the min_replica.
If the last pod lives in the scaled-up nodes(node D), It can't delete the last pod and rearrange it to original nodes(A, B or C). 
This will raise an issue: extra node fee

Is this an ordinary situation? Or I should do something to workaround it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your Kubernetes cluster hosted? And are you using Kubernetes autoscaler for Node scaling?

Comment: My clister is on GCP and Cluster Autoscaling is enabled. That's why when HPA scales up some deployment pods, it will also cause cluster autoscaling. But when HPA scales down, HPA starts to remove Pods. If there is only one pod left in scaled-up Node, HPA will not able to scale down, and the scaled-up node will remain unutilized.

Comment: The other situation is when the cluster is scaled up, at this time,  I re-deploy a deployment(due to update), this deployment will be deployed on a scaled-up node. It will also cause the scaled-up node never scale down thereafter

Comment: reproduce step: 
1. Create a cluster with cluster auto-scaling enabled.
2. deploy a deployment with HPA.
3. increase HPA loading, trigger the cluster to scale up.
4. re-deploy other deployment(called Z) at this time, and this deployment(Z) will be deployed on the scaled-up node.
5. decrease HPA loading, trigger the cluster to scale down.
6. the node with deployment(Z) will never scale down thereafter.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2552#issuecomment-295259290

Comment: You can try to evict pods from node on schedule using `kubectl drain <nodename>`